# How to write csv file in descending order in python without using third-party packages such as pandas?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

```
ProductMaster = { 1 : [Minor Widget,0.25,250]
                  2 : [Critical Widget,5.00,10]
                  3 : [Complete System (Basic),500,1]
                  4 : [Complete System (Deluxe),625,1]
                }
```

I got the dictionary (ProductMaster) above by reading a csv file and then I did some calculation to make the dictionary (productReport) below.

```
productReport = { 1 : [687500.0,11000,0.0]
                  2 : [250000.0,5000,12500.0]
                  3 : [1500000.0,3000,92500.0]
                  4 : [0,0,0]
                }
```

The first index of the list value in dictionary (productReport) above represents gross revenue, and I want to output a csv file using the dictionary above in descending order in terms of gross revenue.

```
with open(ProductReport_Filename, 'w') as file:

    csvWriter = csv.writer(file)

    csvWriter.writerow(["Name","GrossRevenue","TotalUnits","DiscountCost"])

    productKeys = ProductMaster.keys()

    for key,value in productReport.items():

        if key in productKeys:

            csvWriter.writerow([ProductMaster[key][0], *value])

    file.close()
```

The code above gives the csv file below:

```
Name,GrossRevenue,TotalUnits,DiscountCost
Minor Widget,687500.0,11000,0.0
Critical Widget,250000.0,5000,12500.0
Complete System (Basic),1500000.0,3000,92500.0
Complete System (Deluxe),0,0,0
```

But I want the csv file to be sorted by gross revenue in descending order. So, the output should be:

```
Name,GrossRevenue,TotalUnits,DiscountCost
Complete System (Basic),1500000.0,3000,92500.0
Minor Widget,687500.0,11000,0.0
Critical Widget,250000.0,5000,12500.0
Complete System (Deluxe),0,0,0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just ignore the keys.  You probably should be storing those in a list instead of a dictionary anyway; dictionaries with incrementing integer keys are not very useful.

So, ignore the keys, grab the values, and sort that list.

```
import csv

ProductMaster = { 1 : ['Minor Widget',0.25,250],
                  2 : ['Critical Widget',5.00,10],
                  3 : ['Complete System (Basic)',500,1],
                  4 : ['Complete System (Deluxe)',625,1]
                }

productReport = { 1 : [687500.0,11000,0.0],
                  2 : [250000.0,5000,12500.0],
                  3 : [1500000.0,3000,92500.0],
                  4 : [0,0,0]
                }

# Build up a combined list.

result = [[pm[0]]+pr for pm,pr in zip(ProductMaster.values(), productReport.values())]
result.sort( key=lambda k: -k[1] )

# Write it.

with open("x.csv", 'w') as file:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(file)
    csvWriter.writerow(["Name","GrossRevenue","TotalUnits","DiscountCost"])
    csvWriter.writerows( result )
```

Output:

```
Name,GrossRevenue,TotalUnits,DiscountCost
Complete System (Basic),1500000.0,3000,92500.0
Minor Widget,687500.0,11000,0.0
Critical Widget,250000.0,5000,12500.0
Complete System (Deluxe),0,0,0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of tuples, then sort the data by gross revenue in descending order.

```
import csv

# Define the dictionaries
ProductMaster = { 1 : ['Minor Widget',0.25,250],
                  2 : ['Critical Widget',5.00,10],
                  3 : ['Complete System (Basic)',500,1],
                  4 : ['Complete System (Deluxe)',625,1]
                }

productReport = { 1 : [687500.0,11000,0.0],
                  2 : [250000.0,5000,12500.0],
                  3 : [1500000.0,3000,92500.0],
                  4 : [0,0,0]
                }

# Create a list of tuples to represent the data
data = []
for key, value in productReport.items():
    data.append((key, ProductMaster[key][0], value[0], value[1], value[2]))

# Sort the data by gross revenue
data_sorted = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)

# Write the data to a CSV file
with open('product_sales_report.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(['Product ID', 'Product Name', 'Gross Revenue', 'Total Units', 'Discount Cost'])
    for row in data_sorted:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value), you may now sort dictionaries.

You can also create a new dictionary, sort and work with that, but if you want to sort the original, use the line

```
productReport = {k: v for k, v in sorted(productReport.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
```

The `reverse` parameter is used to return a descending order.

The complete program is below, along with an output:

```
import csv

ProductMaster = { 1 : ["Minor Widget",0.25,250],
                  2 : ["Critical Widget",5.00,10],
                  3 : ["Complete System (Basic)",500,1],
                  4 : ["Complete System (Deluxe)",625,1]
                }

productReport = { 1 : [687500.0,11000,0.0],
                  2 : [250000.0,5000,12500.0],
                  3 : [1500000.0,3000,92500.0],
                  4 : [0,0,0]
                }

with open("c:/users/queen/documents/testexcel.csv", 'w') as file:

    csvWriter = csv.writer(file)

    csvWriter.writerow(["Name","GrossRevenue","TotalUnits","DiscountCost"])

    productKeys = ProductMaster.keys()

    # Use 
    productReport = {k: v for k, v in sorted(productReport.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

    for key,value in productReport.items():

        if key in productKeys:

            csvWriter.writerow([ProductMaster[key][0], *value])

    file.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to do something without code rewriting.

One of solutions is to sort `productReport` dictionary by first item of key's list (in other words, according GrossRevenue)

```
import operator
productReport = { 1 : [687500.0,11000,0.0],
                  2 : [250000.0,5000,12500.0],
                  3 : [1500000.0,3000,92500.0],
                  4 : [0,0,0]
                }

print(dict(sorted(productReport.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)))
```

The dictionary will be sorted by the keys' lists. Meanwhile, lists are automatically sorted according to the first inner element. We add `reverse` argument to make them be sorted in  descending order.

The output will look like

```
{ 3: [1500000.0, 3000, 92500.0], 
  1: [687500.0, 11000, 0.0], 
  2: [250000.0, 5000, 12500.0], 
  4: [0, 0, 0]
}
```

So, we should add one row and change the variable

```
    ...

    productKeys = ProductMaster.keys()
    
    sorted_productReport = dict(sorted(
                                productReport.items(), 
                                key=operator.itemgetter(1), 
                                reverse=True))

    for key,value in sorted_productReport.items():

        if key in productKeys:

            csvWriter.writerow([ProductMaster[key][0], *value])
```

Answer (score 0):

The builtin sorted method can be used to sort a dictionary. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

```
sorted(productReport.items(), key = lambda x:x[1][0],reverse=True)
```

Passing an iterable dictionary items, with key being a callback function which sorts using the first list item and reverse flag for sorting with a descending order.

The output of sorted is always a list.

```
[(3, [1500000.0, 3000, 92500.0]), (1, [687500.0, 11000, 0.0]), (2, [250000.0, 5000, 12500.0]), (4, [0, 0, 0])]
```

You can easily convert it to dictionary with dict()

```
dict(sorted(productReport.items(), key = lambda x:x[1][0],reverse=True))
>>> {3: [1500000.0, 3000, 92500.0], 1: [687500.0, 11000, 0.0], 2: [250000.0, 5000, 12500.0], 4: [0, 0, 0]}
```